# Handle calling of undefined abstract method C#

Tags: c#, serialization, error-handling, deserialization, abstract

I have an abstract class which calls one of its abstract methods, as so:

```
public abstract class VirtualAsset : ISerializable
{
    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        SerializeAsset(info);
    }

    public abstract void SerializeAsset(SerializationInfo info);
}
```

The problem is, due to the fact that I am trusting user input, it is highly possible that a malicious user (or a user who doesn't know what they are doing) could try to pass in an instance of VirtualAsset, instead of a subclass that implements the needed abstract function... In fact, when I purposefully do this, the program crashes without error.

I've tried using a try-catch to no avail... What is the best way to handle this problem effectively? Do I have to check self.GetType() every time I call overridable methods?

Comment: If VirtualAsset is abstract, how could someone pass it around?

Comment: You'll need to clarify a bit, I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: How do you "purposefully do this"? Since it's not possible, I'm curious ;)

Comment: I'm using Unity3D, in their inspector I have a script attached to a GameObject with an array of VirtualAsset. Unity threw me no errors when I created this array, but I'm looking into the possibility that Unity its self is crashing when I run the scene and not my code

Comment: It is definitely not crashing JUST because I have instances of the abstract class. Unity offers me no way of showing me whether or not it has actually instantiated any members of my abstract class though, so it's hard to say... I still worry that this could be exploited by a malicious user if Unity is allowing "fake instances" of abstract classes.

Comment: Your abstract class is not getting instantiated.

Comment: @Siege I can't believe I missed the fact that they could be null. Still, something strange, if attempting to use a null object, wouldn't that send a null reference exception? that does explain how Unity was able to display a list of such instances without there actually being instances EDIT: your comment appears to have been deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is, due to the fact that I am trusting user input, it is highly possible that a malicious user (or a user who doesn't know what they are doing) could try to pass in an instance of VirtualAsset

No, it's not possible. An abstract class cannot be instantiated, by definition. Nobody will ever be able to create an instance of `VirtualAsset`, and any derived class that doesn't implement the abstract method will have to be abstract as well.

Comment: Is this a new functionality since .NET 2.0? Because I am somehow seeing instances of my abstract class. I'm using Unity3d if that helps, I suppose what Unity is showing me could be ghost-instances, a possible glitch in Unity

Comment: @GeorgesOatesLarsen, no it's not new. It has always been there, and not just in C#, it's true for most (all?) OO languages. I don't know about Unity, but if you're seeing an instance of an abstract class, there must be something very wrong going on...

Comment: I agree, Unity clearly has something very strange going on... I am going to ask the Unity community about this, thankyou for the answer! Will accept in 3 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Since one can't create instance of an abstract class this problem does not exist for verifiable code.

Now if one passes a name of class and you try to create such class creation will fail. It will fail because abstract class can't be created, but not because it tries to call abstract method.